# How can I force full screen mode with SCNView on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, fullscreen, scnview

If I am creating a SCNView its fullscreen on iPad simulator, but on iPhone its just a vertical centered frame. The width is correct, but the height is too small. I tried a lot, but nothing has an effect on the size of the SCNView.

What I tried:

- SCNView.init(frame)
- "Presentation" (Fullscreen) on Main.storyboard (Game View Controller)
- different Content Modes (SceneKit View)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Same problem...

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem, make sure that in Info.plist the "UILaunchStoryboardName" points to "LaunchScreen".